# Eloquent laravel error

Tags: php, orm, laravel, model, eloquent

In laravel I create model named 'Test':

`class Test extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'test';
}`

then run `composer dump-autoload` then I use this code in controller :

`$arr = Test::first();
dd($arr);`

but this error appear:

`Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Call to undefined method Test::first()`

Comment: Show your real code if you want real answer

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question.

Comment: Actually, it should work. If you do `$test = new Test` do you get any error?

Comment: Where I can do `$test = new Test` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably not using that same Test class (extended from Eloquent), to be sure, you can get the full path of it by doing:

```
$reflector = new ReflectionClass('Test');

dd($reflector->getFileName());
```

Comment: Great,I find the problem. The class is migration class not model class.Two classes named 'Test'.